# Java jumping between blocks of code

Tags: java, batch-file, field, goto

Is there a way to jump between Fields of code?

At the moment I am making a calculator and I want the code to be able to jump between fields similar to the GOTO command in the .Batch, for example.

```
private void MinusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    (A) 

    operator = 2;
    Extradigitreal = 0;
    Secondigit = displayvalue;
    displayvalue = 0.0;
    jTextField1.setText(Double.toString(displayvalue));
    decimal=0;   
}

private void Minuskeypressed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
     Goto A
}
```

I know the GOTO command doesn't exist, but is there any other way to create something similar because some of the text is computer generated and therefore un-editable, this means I cannot create loops. It would save a lot of space as some of the voids contain over 80 lines of text and since I have at so many I would be wasting over 1000 lines of text causing unnecessary memory loss.

Comment: If else statements, multiple methods

Comment: What? Why don't you use methods to switch context? Do you really intend to write a calculator in just one big block of code? Also what do you mean, computer generated text?

Comment: If you must ask for goto there is something wrong with the overall design of your application. I would say the way you are trying to do it is impractical. Look into methods.

Comment: @Renan, what I meant by computer generated text, is that I used the Netbeans Function Design view using Jpanels and Jbuttons, so randomly generated text was made, including the private void MinusActionPerformed on each Method

Answer (score 2):

If this is what you want:

```
private void Minuskeypressed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
   Goto A
```

`A` is defined in the code you posted in the question, you can simply write

```
private void Minuskeypressed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    MinusActionPerformed(evt);
}
```

In the future, please follow the Java Naming Conventions and start methods with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the miscommunication, what I was trying to get at is use a shortcut in the Minuskeypressed method to goto the MinusActionPerformed to save space and time.